# echo 1 > sudo /sys/block/sdX/device/delete command

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

I am trying to delete a scsi disk using below command `echo 1 > sudo /sys/block/sdb/device/delete`. When I try to `lsscsi` after the command, I am still able to see the disk.

That would be great if some one can point where I am going wrong.

Comment: That command will create a file in the current directory called `sudo` with a line containing a single digit `1`.

Answer (score 5):

Where you're going wrong is in your understanding of how output redirection works.

Kusalananda's comment explains what happens -- the output of `echo` is directed into a file named `sudo` in the local directory. `1` and `/sys/block/sdb/device/delete` are arguments to `echo`, you'll find them in the output file.

Similarly, `sudo echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete` won't work, because the `sudo` has not started yet when the shell sets up the output redirection.

If you really want to do it this way rather than su to root for a moment, you'll want:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete'
```

`tee` takes the input from `stdin` and writes it to the file specified as well as `stdout`, and can be run as root via `sudo`. In the latter command, the whole shell process runs under `sudo`.